# Converting String to Date is Formatting Year Incorrectly

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a string "05/09/20" to a Date format that will display the entire year.

This seems to be a simple enough process however SimpleDateFormat is returning the year as "0020"

Here is a sample code

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  
public class StringToDateExample1 {  
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {  
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  String dateInString="05/09/20";
  Date date =  formatter.parse(dateInString);
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
}  
}
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Note: if I set simple date format to MM/dd/yy, it understands that the year is 2020

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: `LocalDate.parse("05/09/20", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu"))` yields `05/09/2020` (only please break up into more statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **parse** with a formatter `"MM/dd/yy"` and **write** with a formatter `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.

This is because formatters simply *shape the representation* of an underlying date. Thus, if you want to read one format, and write a different one, you need to use one formatter to read into a date by converting a string of the format it expects into a date object (which does not have an intrinsic format), then pass that date to a *different* formatter which shapes it into the format you want to write in.

So, you'll be doing the following:

```
"05/09/20" (string of a certain format) 
-A-> 
{May Ninth 2020} (date, no specific format, it's just an object) 
-B-> 
"05/09/2020" (date expressed as a string in a different format)
```

Note that `B` is not the reverse of `A`, therefore a single formatter cannot perform both.